# imediacontrol->run returns E_ACCESSDENIED while running the graph in c++

Tags: c++, com, directshow

I am trying to understand direct show and filters.For that I have downloaded code ([from  here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80413/Streaming-Server-using-Direct-Show-and-Windows-Med)) and I am able to run it .exe given in release folder. But now when I try to run that using visual studio 2010, following line

```
hr = m_pMediaControl -> Run( );
```

returns `E_ACCESSDENIED`. I tried to find answer on internet but didn't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

This error is untypical and what happens is the Filter Graph Manager is unable to perform once of its internal tasks and then it forwards the error code back from internal operation to the caller (you). One of the filters in the graph could report failure on its state transition.

To troubleshoot this problem, you need to check the topology of the filter graph and then attempt to remove some of the filter until you get rid of the error. You will isolate the problem to specific filter.

Comment: I have tried to remove audio filter. after that it starts giving E_FAIL. If anything is problematic with filter then how am I able to run exe that is in release folder without any problem. Have you tried to run it? Can you pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

If the application works when running it one way but not another, then it could be related to accessing the directory from which it is executed, such as a permissions problem. For example, perhaps you have a file sink which is trying to write to the current directory? If the file sink cannot write its output file, it will return an error such as `E_ACCESSDENIED` once `IMediaControl->Run()` is invoked. So - check your output paths and make sure you can create files and write to that directory.

As Roman points out, systematically removing filters one by one is probably the best way to isolate the error. It can be very helpful to either save the graph you created to a `GRF` file and inspect it with GraphEdit where you can experiment with it, or register the objects at runtime and play with the graph dynamically. Both these techniques are described in the DirectShow documentation on MSDN.